# How to access JS object property in node.js native addon

Tags: node.js, v8, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I have a native Node.js addon with a exported method called `findMatchingRules` which I will call as follows(example):

`findMatchingRules({name: "test", email: "email@test.com"})`

This is the basic addon I have written yet:

```
#include <node.h>

void FindMatchingRule(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    v8::Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(0);
}

void Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "findMatchingRules", FindMatchingRule);
}

NODE_MODULE(module_name, Initialize)
```

How can I access `args[0]["name"]` in the `FindMatchingRule` method, without creating a mapper class because my input can be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Try studying [the Node.js Addons documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), and for more details the [V8 API documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-12.0/).

Specifically, [this](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_function_arguments) shows how to access the arguments of your C++ callback (the key part being `args[0]->As<Object>()`), and [this](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-12.0/db/d85/classv8_1_1_object.html) shows that `Object`s have a `Get(context, key)` method to retrieve their properties.